# reusable contentview .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui, contentview

Simply, I have a contentview such as;

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myapp.customstacklayout">
    <StackLayout>


        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="header">

                <!-- some title things here, such as a header label etc-->

            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="content">

                <!--Contents should be added here when reused-->


            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="footer">

                <!-- some footer things here, such as a summary label etc-->

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--Not here-->

    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

and i want to reuse it in a ContentPage such as;

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mycontrols="clr-namespace:myapp"
             x:Class="myapp.mainpage">

    <StackLayout>
        <mycontrols:customstacklayout>

            <Button Text="TestButton"/>
            <Entry Text="TestEntry"/>
            <Label Text="TestLabel"/>
                .... and etc..

        </mycontrols:customstacklayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

to create such a reusable item, i think, in xaml, there has to be something for contentview to point which IView item the children should be added in

Any idea or a piece of code for that?

Thanks in advance.

Ender

EDIT: i changed my contentview xaml for using ControlTemplate. Added Resources and a contentPresenter at the point where i want to show the children added. But still can not see the children

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myapp.customstacklayout">
    <ContentView.Resources x:Key="template">
    <ControlTemplate>
    <StackLayout>


        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="header">

                <!-- some title things here, such as a header label etc-->

            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="content">

                <!--Contents should be added here when reused-->
                    <ContentPresenter/>


            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="footer">

                <!-- some footer things here, such as a summary label etc-->

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--Not here-->

    </StackLayout>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentView.Resources>

</ContentView>
```

Comment: You're looking for something like [Control Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate) in combination with a [Content Presenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you want to create a reusable `ContentView` .NET MAUI, you can create `Control Templates` with `Content Presenter` and then **reuse** it in the page you want.

You can refer to below detailed steps on how to use it.

**1.** Create a custom control: **CustomControl.xaml** that inherits from `ContentView` with a `custom` BindableProperty like below:

**XAML:**

```
<ContentView.ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate>

        <Frame>

            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>

                <ContentPresenter/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ControlTemplate>
    
    
</ContentView.ControlTemplate>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class CustomControl : ContentView 
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl) );

    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Title
    {

        get => GetValue(TitleProperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);

    }
}
```

**2.** You can reuse it multiples in the `MainPage.xaml` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiAppCustomDemo.Controls"
             x:Class="MauiAppCustomDemo.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">


            <controls:CustomControl Title="Hello World">
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Label 1"/>
                    <Label Text="Label 2"/>

                </VerticalStackLayout>
                
            </controls:CustomControl>

            <controls:CustomControl Title="Hello again">

                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Label 3"/>
                    <Label Text="Label 4"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </controls:CustomControl>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Microsoft Official reference link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @Ender KARADAG I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here. If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you Alexandar. I just saw your answer. That seems to be the correct answer. Thank you. Do i have declare that ControlTemplate in My contentview's ContentView.Resources? i did it, but i got an exception "Position 8:10. resources in ResourceDictionary require a x:Key attribute" tough i declared a x:Key for that

Comment: Hi Alexandar. Now i tested it. It works like a charm. Thank you